# error while checking double space in name column

Tags: r

i am updating the new column which will show if the name column have double space or extra space but its showing error.

i havemore than one column in my database

```
df7 <- data.frame(name_1 = c("ttt, hbue","mna,ssu huna","vga,  pahk","hja, dhyn","cct, indo","nhu,nhuv"))

countSpaces <- function(s) { sapply(gregexpr(" ", s), function(p) { sum(p>=0) } ) }
name <-  "name_1"

df7 <- df7 %>% mutate(across(`1. double space in name` = ifelse(countSpaces(df7[[name]])>1,"1. name contains uneccessary space"," ")))
```

[image]

Comment: Why are we using "across"? Code works fine without it.

Comment: Try: ```df7 %>% mutate(`1. double space in name` = ifelse(countSpaces(!!sym(name)) > 1, "yes","no"))```